# Allowing users to 'follow' taxonomy terms. Then creating a view which displays a list of nodes which are assigned the 'followed terms'

Tags: 6, notifications, taxonomy-terms

I'm looking for the recipe which emulates a feature from the popular tech blog: Mashable.com

Here's what I'm looking for:

1. Nodes are assigned taxonomy terms.
2. Users may view a node, and see the taxonomy terms which are assigned to this node.
3. Users may 'follow/subscribe' to each taxonomy term assigned to this node.
4. A custom view (called "My Custom Stories") will be configured, for each user, which displays a list of nodes which are relevant to the taxonomy terms to which he subscribed.

For example:

1. A node X is created which is assigned the terms 'Politics', 'Apple', and 'China'.
2. User A follows/subscribes to 'Politics', while User B follows 'Apple'.
3. User A's 'My Custom Stories' view will only contain a list of nodes which are assigned the 'Politics' taxonomy term, while User B will see a list of 'Apple' nodes.

I'm particularly interested in the 'taxonomy term follow' modules required for this recipe, as well as how the 'Custom Stories' view will be configured.

I'd appreciate any tips. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My idea:

You could create a new content type Taxonomy Subscriptions, using taxonomy and user reference (you will need References module).

Then with Rules module you could manage (create) the subscriptions for terms and then you view will be joined with the created content type.